# Soap API Call not working properly/no methods found

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl

I am attempting to make a call to a soap api. I have to wsdl file and have used svcutil to create a proxy class called "PublicPortalServiceJSONPortTypeClient". I have followed the microsoft documentation for making calls using svcutil, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I am using dotnet framework 6 cli
This project is using the console app template

Error:
`System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.    at System.ServiceModel.MessageSecurityOverHttp.CreateSecurityBindingElement(Boolean isSecureTransportMode, Boolean isReliableSession, MessageSecurityVersion version)    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpSecurity.CreateMessageSecurity(Boolean isReliableSessionEnabled, MessageSecurityVersion version)    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateMessageSecurity()    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBindingBase.CreateBindingElements()    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements() cd25037@MacBook-Air-(2) PowerschoolAPI % dotnet run /Users/cd25037/dev/git/cs/PowerschoolAPI/Program.cs(4,7): warning CS0105: The using directive for 'Sys olAPI.csproj] System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.    at System.ServiceModel.MessageSecurityOverHttp.CreateSecurityBindingElement(Boolean isSecureTranspo    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpSecurity.CreateMessageSecurity(Boolean isReliableSessionEnabled, Messa    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateMessageSecurity()    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBindingBase.CreateBindingElements()    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements() cd25037@MacBook-Air-(2) PowerschoolAPI % dotnet run System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.    at System.ServiceModel.MessageSecurityOverHttp.CreateSecurityBindingElement(Boolean isSecureTranspo    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpSecurity.CreateMessageSecurity(Boolean isReliableSessionEnabled, Messa    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateMessageSecurity() cd25037@MacBook-Air-(2) PowerschoolAPI % dotnet run System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.    at System.ServiceModel.MessageSecurityOverHttp.CreateSecurityBindingElement(Boolean isSecureTranspo    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpSecurity.CreateMessageSecurity(Boolean isReliableSessionEnabled, Messa    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateMessageSecurity()    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBindingBase.CreateBindingElements()    at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements()    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.EnsureInvariants(String contractName)    at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint.EnsureInvariants()    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEn    at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()    at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.System.ServiceModel.IAsyncCommunicationObject.O    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncInternal(TimeSpan timeout)    at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletion(Task task)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Open()    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /Users/cd25037/dev/git/cs/PowerschoolAPI/Program.cs:line 30`

Code:

```
using ServiceReference;
using System.ServiceModel;

// Create the binding.
WSHttpBinding myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest;

// Create the endpoint address. Note that the machine name
// must match the subject or DNS field of the X.509 certificate
// used to authenticate the service.
EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("https://fccps.powerschool.com:8443/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON.PublicPortalServiceJSONHttpsSoap11Endpoint/");

// Create the client. The code for the calculator
// client is not shown here. See the sample applications
// for examples of the calculator code.
PublicPortalServiceJSONPortTypeClient cc = new PublicPortalServiceJSONPortTypeClient(myBinding, ea);
// The client must provide a user name and password. The code
// to return the user name and password is not shown here. Use
// a database to store the user name and passwords, or use the
// ASP.NET Membership provider database.
cc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "pearson";
cc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "m0bApP5";
try
{
    // Begin using the client.
    // cc.Abort();
    // await cc.OpenAsync();
    // await cc.loginAsync("","",0);
    cc.Open();
    var login = await cc.loginToPublicPortalAsync("<redacted>", "<redacted>");
    

    // cc.Close();
}
catch(Exception e){
     Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

WSDL source: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uN2PJvS7Iz8XOpJDeBivxM4Wv3fI39jq-8G_No8LEa8/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried all of the functions contained within the proxy class and none of them work, including  cc.open();. I have used all of the soap endpoints found within the wsdl source for the endpoint uri.

Comment: I think the issue may be the WSHttpBinding itself. I know that it was not supported in .NET Core and have not seen any rumblings about it being supported in .NET 6. Does the server accept other types of bindings? If not, you may need to go with NET 4.8.

Comment: WSHHttpBindings are supported through nuget packages found here: https://www.nuget.org/profiles/corewcf.

Comment: Are you sure that the server will support WSHttpBinding? Perhaps you should try a different binding such as BasicHttpBinding, CustomBinding, NetHttpBinding, or NetTcpBinding.